# call relation in accessor function

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, accessor

I want to call relation into accessors function with less query

ticket has many messages
ticket model has accessors function 
I want into accessors function  **if ticket->messages()->exist() == TRUE** returns message`s body, or ** if ticket->messages()->exist() == TRUE**  returns ticket`s body
this line code ($ticket->last_body)  in view make one Query for each row and i want to decrease my query

**Ticket model**:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TicketMessage::class, 'ticket_id');
    }

    public function getLastBodyAttribute()
    {

        if($this->messages()->exists()){
            return $this->messages()->orderByDesc('created_at')->first()->body;
        } else {
            return $this->body;
        }
    }
}
```

Ticket massage belongsto tickets

**TicketMessage model** :

```
class TicketMessage extends Model
{
    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class,'ticket_id');
    }
}
```

I get tickets with own relationships and passed to view
**TicketController**:

```
class TicketController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::with('messages')
                        ->where('status', 'open')
                        ->get();

        return view('ticket::supporter.supporter', compact('tickets'));
    }
}
```

```
this line code $ticket->last_body make one Query for each row and i want to decrease my query 

**supporter.blade** :

    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <a href="{{url(Route('show_client_ticket', ['id' => $ticket->id]))}}">   
            {{$ticket->subject}} 
        </a>

        <p style="color: #959A9D;">
            {{$ticket->last_body}} //this line returns too much  Query
        </p>
        <hr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this.

```
 public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class,'ticket_id');
    }
```

to this.

```
 public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class,'id');
    }
```

because the default primary key of the model is "id".

or if you want to change the primary key. try this:

```
class Ticket extends Model
 {
  protected $primaryKey = 'ticket_id';

...
```